# How can i preg_match multiple words

Tags: php

i'm trying to make the input not a pattern.

```
$input= "words trying to compare";

preg_match("/\b{$input}\b/", "these are a lot of words that i'm trying to compare") 
              // ^this might contain multiple words, but the same as ^^ these
echo "match is found";
```

how can i make it that the even if the input words are not in the same order as the sentence i'm trying to compare it to, it could return "match found."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
preg_match_all("/\b{$input}\b/", "these are a lot of words that i'm trying to compare",$matchedWords);
```

For multiple words:

```
<?php
$input= "words compare";
$pattern = str_replace(" ","|",$input);
preg_match_all("/{$pattern}/", "these are a lot of words that i'm trying to compare words",$matchedWords);
              // ^this might contain multiple words, but the same as ^^ these
var_dump($matchedWords);
```

Comment: I just tried that and when the input is "words compare"(searching it in the wrong order) it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Glad that I helped you. Don't forget to accept the answer to close this question

Answer (score 0):

```
$input= "words|trying|to|compare";
$count = preg_match_all('#\b('.$input.')\b#', $string, $matches);

if($count)
 echo 'found word';
else
 echo 'not found';
```